# Redirect Loop in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, redirect, ip

I'm working on a CakePHP application. I'm trying to redirect the user to admin URL based on his/her IP address and for that I'm using this code in app_controller.php

```
        if(env('REMOTE_ADDR')=='foo') {

        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index', 'admin'=>1));
        echo $html->link(__('Logout', true), array('controller'=> 'users', 'action'=>'admin_index')); 
        }
```

I'm getting a redirect loop as soon the condition matches. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your app controller fires code before anything else. The code you've written essentially translates to

1. Visit URL => AppController fires, sends you to /admin/controller/index/
2. In /admin/controller/index/ AppController fires again and sends you to /admin/controller/index/
3. As above

Another thing, you seem to be echoing a link after you do a redirect, this doesn't serve any purpose.

What you probably want is something like this

```
$url = 'Wherever you are redirecting to';
if (env('REMOTE_ADDR') == 'foo' && $this->params['url']['url'] != $url) {
   $this->redirect($url);
}
```

Also, when you do `$this->redirect(array('action'=>'index', 'admin'=>1));` you're essentially redirecting to the index action of whichever URL you are in. Is this what you're trying to do? If so, you'll need to modify your check to something like

```
$url = 'Wherever you are redirecting to';
if (env('REMOTE_ADDR') == 'foo' && $this->params['action'] != 'index' && $this->params['admin'] != 1) {
   $this->redirect($url);
}
```

Comment: Hello John, thanks for the reply, I used the code above but I'm still getting the redirect loop error. :(

Comment: Oh well, sorry, it just worked, the FTP server had not uploaded the file. :P